# jquery getting value of span is empty, html is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 divs with a random number inside of them

When calling `$("#result1 span").text()` the output is blank. However when calling `$("#result1 span").html()` the output gives the value.

How can I get the value without the html?

The output is like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #number {position:relative; top:-225px;left:584px;width:230px;height:10px;}
        #number span {padding:14px; margin:2px; color:orange; font-size:30px;}
        #number input:hover{opacity:0.9; filter:alpha(opacity=90);}
        #number input{opacity:1.0; filter:alpha(opacity=100);}
        #generate {position:relative; top:35px; left:-1px; width:95px; height:25px;}
        #reset {position:relative; top:35px; left:5px; width:95px; height:25px;}
    </style>1
```

The value I need is right after the closing `</style>` tag `"1"`

Full html:

```
<div id="number">
<span id="result1"></span>
<span id="result2"></span>
<span id="result3"></span>
<span id="result4"></span>
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<button id="reset">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#result1').html((Math.random() * 10) >> 0);
$('#result2').html((Math.random() * 10) >> 0);
$('#result3').html((Math.random() * 10) >> 0);
$('#result4').html((Math.random() * 10) >> 0);
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve the `1` character, could you show the element in which that `1` appears? Up to, and including, the element that has the `id` by which you're basing your selection?

Comment: Can you post your full html, including the span you're talking about? Otherwise it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Did you tried `$("#result1 span").val()`

Comment: I tried .val .text .html, also updated post thank you for your time

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do here, but the `style` element should be placed in `head` according to the [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#edef-STYLE).

Comment: So you set the number ? then you want to get the number ? just use a `var` in the first place !

Comment: @Kyle, please post the HTML as requested. Otherwise this is a guessing game, since we can't see what's going wrong. Ideally it'd be great if you could *also* set up a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo.

Comment: Where is the style stuff coming from? From the html you posted, it doesn't seem anywhere near the span.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: HTML5 [allows for scoped style](http://www.impressivewebs.com/scoped-styles-html5/), so the `style` element isn't restricted to the `head` of the document.

Comment: I added my full script thank you everyone for taking your time to help

Comment: @DavidThomas, oh yeah that's right. Totally forgot about it! But I don't like it and would advice against it. Separation of HTML and CSS is considered good practice where I come from :)

Comment: I'm ashamed. It was with my PHP echoing the style on every call it generated a number... I didn't see this before it's not displayed unless you view the page source. That explains why JS displayed it with .html or .innerhtml. FML. Thanks everyone for the help I apologize for the amateur mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing at least-- your selector is wrong.  $("#result1 span").text() isn't going to give you anything because there is no span *inside* result1, result1 *is* a span. Change your selector to $("#result1") and see what you get.

simply changing the selector works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/ccross59/TnbCc/1/

Comment: @Kyle, edited my answer with a fiddle so you can see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (This should return the text inside all 4 spans one by one)

```
$("#result1 span").each (function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much, much easier if you can put the "need this text" inside a span with an id -- then you just grab that id's .text().  If you can't change the markup, you can grab span's .html() and string match for content after "", but that's quite fragile.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I didn't have to do that. That would be more work than it needed to be. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think i see your problem.
$("#result1 span").text() witch would be equivalent to $('#result1').find('span') will find the text of the first span nested in "#result1"

it looks like "#result1" dose not have any nested spans and you in fact want the text value of the span that is "#result1".

If i am correct $('#result1').text() is the code you are looking for.

Comment: No need to be sorry this is a common part of the learning curve for css style selectors.  I have suffered from the same confusion early on.